# Generic Methods pass in a delegate to the method?

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to have a generic method that requires a delegate(?) for a method or just a code block to be passed in as a parameter?

Say I have AddJob() and AddJob2(). I want these passed into a Generic method that runs some skeleton code but then executes the AddJob or AddJob2.

Thanks!

Edit:
I'm on .net 2.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure:

```
public void AddJob(string jobName) { ... }
public void AddJob2(string jobName) { ... }

public void RunAddJob(Action addJob)
{
    ...
    addJob();
}

static void Main()
{
    RunAddJob(() => AddJob("job1"));
    RunAddJob(() => AddJob2("job2"));
}
```

**Edit:** the non-generic `System.Action` is new in .NET 3.5. For .NET 2.0, you can assume:

```
public delegate void Action();
```

Comment: Is it possible to not supply jobName if you don't know what parameters are passed into the functions AddJob and AddJob2?

Thanks

Comment: @Adam if I've understood correctly, I can amend the answer to demonstrate

Comment: ...although the `RunAddJob` method in the example no longer needs to be generic if I do that.

Comment: Yeah what you'e changed it too is what I'm looking for I think!

Is Action still required though? not Delegate?

Comment: Not Delegate: you need to deal with a concrete delegate type. `System.Delegate` is the abstract base class for all delegate types. `System.Action` and `System.Func` are various concrete delegate types, for different sets of parameter and return types.

Comment: OK that makes sense, but isn't Action a generic itself?

Well what I mean it's definition is Action<T>?

Comment: There's a bunch of different `Action` delegates, with the same name but with different numbers of generic parameters. Here I used `Action`, which accepts no parameters and returns nothing, so there's no need for it to be generic. There's also `Action<T>`, which accepts one parameter; the type of parameter is generic. Likewise `Action<T1, T2>`, `Action<T1, T2, T3>` etc. All of these are treated as different types even though they have the same name.

Comment: Sorry saw that, believe it's because I'm on .net 2.0 which doesn't have just Action!

Comment: Apologies - none of this makes unless you have the docs for .NET 3.5 or above in front of you.

Comment: @Adam: I added that you were on .NET 2.0 to the question.  I hope that doesn't bother you.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the Enumerable class (for LINQ) works like that.

```
T MyFunc<T>(T t, Func<T, T> addjob)
{
    return addjob(t);
}


MyFunc(5, i => i + 10);
```